# How to change title text color in Leaflet for R?

Tags: css, r, shiny, leaflet

I'm trying to change the style / color of the heading for the slider title "Magnitudes", but I can't figure out what to do.  I've tried adding things like 
p {color: red} to the tags$style line, like this:

```
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}", "p {color=white}"),
```

to no avail.  Any ideas?  I don't think it's something you change in the actual sliderInput function itself, but rather CSS, I just can't quite figure it out.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(RColorBrewer)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
  absolutePanel(top = 10, right = 10,
    sliderInput("range", "Magnitudes", min(quakes$mag), max(quakes$mag),
      value = range(quakes$mag), step = 0.1
    ),
    selectInput("colors", "Color Scheme",
      rownames(subset(brewer.pal.info, category %in% c("seq", "div")))
    ),
    checkboxInput("legend", "Show legend", TRUE)
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Reactive expression for the data subsetted to what the user selected
  filteredData <- reactive({
    quakes[quakes$mag >= input$range[1] & quakes$mag <= input$range[2],]
  })

  # This reactive expression represents the palette function,
  # which changes as the user makes selections in UI.
  colorpal <- reactive({
    colorNumeric(input$colors, quakes$mag)
  })

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    # Use leaflet() here, and only include aspects of the map that
    # won't need to change dynamically (at least, not unless the
    # entire map is being torn down and recreated).
    leaflet(quakes) %>% addTiles() %>%
      fitBounds(~min(long), ~min(lat), ~max(long), ~max(lat))
  })

  # Incremental changes to the map (in this case, replacing the
  # circles when a new color is chosen) should be performed in
  # an observer. Each independent set of things that can change
  # should be managed in its own observer.
  observe({
    pal <- colorpal()

    leafletProxy("map", data = filteredData()) %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      addCircles(radius = ~10^mag/10, weight = 1, color = "#777777",
        fillColor = ~pal(mag), fillOpacity = 0.7, popup = ~paste(mag)
      )
  })

  # Use a separate observer to recreate the legend as needed.
  observe({
    proxy <- leafletProxy("map", data = quakes)

    # Remove any existing legend, and only if the legend is
    # enabled, create a new one.
    proxy %>% clearControls()
    if (input$legend) {
      pal <- colorpal()
      proxy %>% addLegend(position = "bottomright",
        pal = pal, values = ~mag
      )
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Cutting straight to the chase:**

Try adding this to your `ui`:

```
tags$style(type = "text/css", 'label[for="range"] {color: white;}'),
```

---

**More detail about how you might figure that out on your own:**

Here's how I'd proceed.

1. Use `runApp()` to run the code you've got, producing a very nice leaflet map in your browser.
2. Right-click on that map and select "View Page Source" to see the source code that's producing the map.
3. Search that source for the string `"Magnitude"`, to find the HTML element that codes for the title you'd like to whiten. Here's what I find when I do that:

   ```
   <label class="control-label" for="range">Magnitudes</label>
   ```
4. From that, construct a CSS selector (here including an ["attribute selector"](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/advanced/attributeselectors/)) that'll find that element, and use it to change the color. Adding this, following the first line of your call to `bootstrapPage()`, does the trick for me:

   ```
   tags$style(type = "text/css", 'label[for="range"] {color: white;}'),
   ```
5. Use `runApp()` again to confirm that the edit worked.

Comment: Thanks for the HTML element trick -- been running out of RStudio so didn't have this option.  Great description, great answer.